# Path information for a python application installed in a different folder per users

Tags: python, tkinter

I am not really certain how to look for this, so I'll just describe the situation.

I am using Python 3.3 to build a cross-platform application using tkinter for a GUI, and cxfreeze to create an installer. What I now wonder is how my application will know where it has been installed?

I plan to distribute some pdf files with the app, but the direct path to these will vary among users (even though the PDF folder will have the same "distance"; it will always be one folder away from the executable after installation).

So, how will I be able to include this path information into my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file system is like so:

```
homedir
  |
  |-bin
  |  |-myapp.py
  |
  |-pdf
     |-file1.pdf
```

just access a PDF by assigning the relative path (as a string) to a variable:

```
pdf_path = "../pdf/file1.pdf"
```

then use your external `start` command by calling `os.system`:

```
import os

os.system("start " + pdf_path)
```

and you should be all set.

Comment: I do not see how I will be able to use this with the `import os`, `os.system("start " + pdf_file)`, since PDF's are not directly openable?

Comment: @Dualinity - what are you trying to do with `os.system("start")`?

Comment: @Dualinity - regardless of what you're doing with `start`, you can pass a file path to a command by saving the path as a variable: `pdf_path = '../pdf/file1.pdf'` then running your `os.system` command

Comment: I tried it, but might it be that when testing it, it won't work, but when it has been installed it will work?

Comment: @Dualinity just set up a dummy installation with your expected path structure and try it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27195/discussion-between-mattdmo-and-dualinity)